# jquery slide div by changing margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making left/right buttons to make a div slide. It slides by changing the left margin.  What I'm trying to do is have it check the left margin and then add/subtract pixels to it. So when the page loads, left margin should be 0.  Then you click the button and it checks the margin, finds it's 0, adds 150 and sets the left margin to 150. And then if you click it again, it checks the margin, finds it's 150 and adds another 150 and sets the margin to 300.

It succeeds in moving the margin from 0 to 150, but i can't get it to go to 300.  I'm thinking it's not able to determine the margin correctly. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks!

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    var pos=$('#contentarea').css("margin-left").replace('px', '');
    pos=pos+150;

    $('#contentarea').animate({ 'margin-left': '-' + pos + 'px'}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: check i have posted answer for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to get current margin-left value, you can use the '+=%value%' and '-=%value%' operators. This will add/substract from the current value the specified value.

```
  $('#left').click(function(){
     $('#contentarea').animate({ 'margin-left': '+=150px'}, 1000);
     return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

use for Get Margin

```
$('#contentarea').css("margin-left")
```

it will return margin default is "PX".

Use For Set Margin

```
$('#contentarea').css("margin-left","Your Size");
```

Default size is "PX" not need to provide size with "PX".

Try this function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#contentarea').css("margin-left", "0");
    });
    $('#left').click(function () {
        var pos = $('#contentarea').css("margin-left");
        var size = 0;
        if (pos == "0px") {
            $('#contentarea').css("margin-left", "150");
        }
        else {
            size = parseInt(pos.slice(0, -2));
            size = size + 150;
        }
        var pos = $('#contentarea').css("margin-left", size);


        $('#contentarea').animate({ 'margin-left': '-' + pos }, 1000);
        return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` instead of `replace` to get css margin left value.

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    var pos = parseInt($('#contentarea').css("margin-left")) + 150;

    $('#contentarea').animate({'margin-left' : '-' + pos + 'px'}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```